# HTML5 Canvas slow on Odroid-X

Tags: android, html5-canvas, odroid

I need a canvas animation as a background for a kiosk-application. I've got an Odroid-X board (detailed informations [here](http://www.hardkernel.com/renewal_2011/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G133999328931)) which i am testing the application on. I'm also testing them on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus Smartphone. My own animation and others i found online are working like a charm on the Smartphone, but its very laggy on the Odroid-X board. I tested it in the Android browser and also in a apk with a WebView in it, same results. Anyone has any Ideas to improve the performance?

Edit: With `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the AndroidManifest.xml it runs smoother but its still a little bit too laggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding the `transform: translateZ(0);` style (and it prefixed versions companions...), which applies a 3D transformation to the DOM element, thus enabling hardware acceleration where available.